# Excel: Calculation of Area of Each Gridcell

Tags: excel, math, coordinates, netcdf

I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this issue I am currently working through. Thanks in advance! My goal is to convert the Out_tonnes_per_year_by_cell units for these emissions to those of flux kg·m−2·s−1--and so first I need to calculate the area of each grid cell before any further unit conversions.

**Problem:**

Calculate the area of each grid cell from only knowing the 1x1 degree coordinates using the following equation:

*(((sin(latitude_1) - sin(latitude_2)) * ((longitude_1) - (longitude_2)) * R^2): where R = the authalic Earth Radius*

**Input Data Reference:**

Emission Inventory Data:
[image]

**Applied Calculation(s):**

(((sin(-90.5) - sin(-89.5)) * ((-180.5) - (-179.5)) * 6371) = *Inconsistent Value*

(((sin(-89.5) - sin(-88.5)) * ((-179.5) - (178.5)) * 6371) = *Inconsistent Value*

(((sin(-88.5) - sin(-87.5)) * ((-178.5) - (177.5)) * 6371) = *Inconsistent Value*

. . .  So on.

**Conclusion:**

Given that this file is already in the .csv format, I would prefer to preform my computations within Excel--but if your potential solution involves a Python-based approach, this would be acceptable as well. Thanks again!

Comment: What about `=(((SIN(-90.5)-SIN(-89.5))*((-180.5)-(-179.5))*6.371))`? It seems you have put comma to number value which is not acceptable. When you will use comma then it will be treated as text and you can't do any arithmetic calculation.

Comment: The "," was added to the post afterwards and does not reflect the computation in Excel. My apologies for the confusion, it should be updated now.

Comment: Then it is calculating...? Are you getting incorrect result?

Comment: I ended up attempting a secondary method, which resolved the issue. Thank you for your help, regardless!